# Angular datepicker change event not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm writing a script in javascript to automate some data entry task on  a webpage.

the page I'm working on has some text areas that won't register (would be treated as empty when the page is submitted) as changed unless I declare a change or input event  like this:

```
var evt = new Event("input", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});        
element.dispatchEvent (evt);
```

there's a datepicker part that accepts manual input or date pick through a calendar thingy.
if I input the date though my code like I'm trying to do, the change again won't register even with the event dispatch like above.

So, how do I input the date and trigger a change event for that element?

I say that the page is but I could be wrong. some elements have classes that have with ng like "ng-star-inserted"

Thank you

I tried using normal event dispatch but I didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write the value date picker's control value accessor (CVA) should receive the value through `input` event. [Here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/595b3daaf6bb77c90cee06481942f1c66b58b2d7/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts#L51) is how the event is handled in the input. Then in the date picker input event handler checks the value provided [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/595b3daaf6bb77c90cee06481942f1c66b58b2d7/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-input-base.ts#L320).

What you can do is provide the value you need like this:

```
var evt = new Event("input", {
  "bubbles":true,
  "cancelable":false,
  "target": {
    "value": "2023-08-01"
  }
});        
element.dispatchEvent (evt);
```

This way date picker will pass the date to its CVA and the change should be recorded correctly.